# my javascript isn't working in IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript

sorry I'm new in javascript and  I find this somewhere in internet and I wrote bad code but this works in chrome...

```
function toggle() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
        $(".class").nariams();
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        $(".class").nariams();
    }
} 

<div class "nariams1"><a  id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();"> 
    <div class="nariams">Nariams </div>       
</div>

<div id="toggleText" style="display: none">
<form id="slick-login">
<label for="username">Prisijungimo vardas</label><input type="text" name="username" class="placeholder" placeholder="vardas">
<label for="password">Slaptažodis</label><input type="password" name="password" class="placeholder" placeholder="slaptažodis">
<input type="submit" value="Prisijungti">
</form>
</div>
```

.nariams is css class which defines button. Shortly I want that when i press button onother class apear. This code works in chrome.

Comment: What exactly does not work as expected?

Comment: What is this supposed to do: `$(".nariams")();`?

Comment: What you have tried. what is the Exception. Please provide more detail.

Comment: What is that `$` function? If some popular library, please tag your question with it.

Comment: it uses a jQuery tag!!!!!!!!

Comment: @TheBrain, jQuery is not the only library that uses $

Comment: But this question has 10 lines of code, and there's a $. The question is tagged `javascript`, `jquery`. What else do you want ?

Comment: The jquery tag wasn't added by the OP.

Comment: @TheBrain, I don't see a jQuery tag.

Comment: The question makes even less sense now. What libraries or external scripts are you using? Could you post the entire HTML page?

Comment: You'll have to forgive us if we seem harsh.  I know it must be difficult to post on an English-speaking forum when your native language is Lithuanian, but we also couldn't figure out at first what you were asking.

Since it seems that you are probably using jQuery, I've created a fiddle with working code: http://jsfiddle.net/G5aRb/.  You'll notice it's a lot less code, a lot simpler, and works well.  I would post the answer here, but I can't because the question has been closed.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Here's a Fiddle of the OP (no changes made to the original code):

http://jsfiddle.net/X49pb/5/

Works for me in Recent Chrome/FF and in IE 9/10.
`$(".class").nariams();` still throws errors as the function `nariams()` isn't included in OP.
It's also still unclear what $ is meant to be, whether it may be jQuery or something else.

Comment: If downvoted please add a comment with the reason, that way I can improve the quality of my posts ;)

Comment: Edited Fiddle and Post, as I began writing the answer before the OP was edited. Now containing merely the fiddle.

Comment: This also isn't good. class appears when I enter site, when i click it disappear(chrome) In IE an Firefox class appear but button do not work like in chrome.

Comment: It's a 1:1 fiddle of your code for others to use, it's not meant as solution.

Comment: I think with code is everything ok, because it works in Chrome (Safari also) like I want. But why it do not work in IE and firefox?

Comment: It works fine in the recent Firefox and IE 9/10 for me. Which versions of IE/FF did you test it with?
Though `$(".class").nariams();` still throws errors, as you didn't include that function in your post

Comment: I use IE9. It should work in earler versions, because not every one who will visit site, will have the newest version of browser...

Comment: In IE9 it shows/hides a small form on click on the word "Nariams" as it also does in Chrome/FF/IE10 for me. What exactly is not working for you? Does the fiddle of your code also not work for you? We basicly need an exact explanation what you want to happen and what does not work (:

Comment: "It's not meant as solution" is probably the reason why this is downvoted. If it's not a solution, it should be a comment.

Comment: I have found that it is problem with my class. If I write only text, javascript works. Sorry for your time. I try to fix html code. Thank you.

Comment: @Juhana Unfortunately I can't comment on other's posts yet :/ And it was downvoted beforehand as my answer still provided reference errors based on a fiddle of the original code that was provided

Comment: It's also been downvoted because you shouldn't have the answer in a fiddle. The answer should be here. You can link to a fiddle if you'd like, but that can't be in place of an actual answer with code here.  The reason is, JSFiddle goes down, and links die.

Comment: @George Stocker It's not an answer in that Fiddle, it's the provided Code. I merely edited my answer afterwards to be just that, as my previous answer was towards older information and thus proven false. I didn't delete & edit the OP, because there were already useful comments present ;)
It's also stated in one line above the Fiddle, that it's a Fiddle of the provided Code (:

Answer (score 0):

Some reasons for this script to fail are:

- `ele` is not found on the page so they return null and later on when you do `ele.style.display` checking it will terminate there.
- `$(".nariams")` must return a function in order to be able to call it like `$(".nariams")()`. Otherwise it will throw an error.

So, it really depends on what the error message in the console says.

Comment: _whatever $(".nariams") returns is undefined or not a function so calling it like $(".nariams")() will throw an error if this is the case_ how can you be so sure about that? You don't know what $() returns. As others already mentioned, it could return another function. #edit, wasn't me who downvoted :)

Comment: @Zim84, you didn't read TheBrain's answer carefully.  He's not saying that's what's happening.  He's saying it's a possible reason the script could be failing but that without further info we can't know.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear to me the way it was written.

Comment: Death threats are not ok, even if said as a joke.

Comment: In any case none of this explains why it would work in Chrome but not in other browsers.

Comment: Anyway, it's a crap question.  However, I think maybe I'll get `$(".nariams")()` copyrighted.  Would look great on a t-shirt! ;)

Comment: I have edited question. I'm new here an I'quite new in javascript....